# Error assembly with monoandroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have an issue with mono.Android 4.6.04000 I have an error which occurs when I try to built the project "Error CS0012: Le type 'Android.App.Activity' est défini dans un assembly qui n'est pas référencé. Vous devez ajouter une référence à l'assembly 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4c4237547e4b6cd'. (CS0012) (MonApp)'

In English that sould be "The type 'Android.App.Activity' is define in an assembly which isn't referenced. You have to add a reference to the assemby 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4c4237547e4b6cd'.

And the assembly mono.Android is well referenced.
So I would like to know how to resolve this problem.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild all your assemblies with the version of Mono for Android you are using. It is because of the [changes to strongnames in 4.6.0](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1476/changes-to-assembly-strongnames-in-xamarin-android-4-6-0).

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by Rebuilt all my assemblies ? It could be very helpful. thanks.

Comment: Rebuild all your projects and referenced projects which were built against pre-4.6.0 tools.